# Дублирование второй буквы в каждом слове C#

Tags: c#, строки

Дана строка:
str = "fjqis mask idwj macs wqeij cnxmsd jkwqe.";
Нужно взять вторую букву каждого слова и добавить её в конец слова.
Хелп.

Comment: задача тривиальная. Но не вижу что бы ты по ней хоть что-то сделал. Здесь помогают делать, а не делают все за тебя. Вопрос противоречит правилам ресурса.

Comment: Я считываю строки из файла, затем проверяю кол-во слов и букв в слове.
С выше описанным я справился, застрял на моменте дублирования

Comment: тебе нужно деление с остатком если кадлую вторую и проблема решена а ну тебя еще легче

Comment: а как проверяш кол0во слов

Comment: @Санитариум
int count = 0;
            foreach (string _s in array)
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count < 2 || count > 50)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Строка должна содержать от 2 до 50 слов");
                }

Comment: так у тебя масссив слов или строка если массив слов это ваще просто или ты строку бьеш на слова

Comment: не с массивом не с обычной строкой я не могу придумать алгоритм.
все упирается в ридонли.
Да и какая разница массив или просто строка, ведь я могу в любой момент сделать join или split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var g = "fjqis mask idwj macs wqeij cnxmsd jkwqe.";

var f = g.Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
{
    var str = f[i].Trim();
    if (str.Length >= 2)
    {
       var first = str[0];
       var other = str.Substring(2);
       f[i] = $"{first}{str[1]}{str[1]}{other}";
     }
}  

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", f));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Как то так.